# nuxt 2.14 generate does not update asyncData

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm following closely to this feature (https://nuxtjs.org/blog/nuxt-static-improvements/#generate-time-cache-vs-full-webpack-build)

I may be getting this wrong, but I hope to clarify if I can use this feature correctly.

Basically, I want to skip the webpack build as highlighted in the article, and build my pages through `nuxt generate`. The thing is that my data source usually changes, but my site code does not, and I thought using the `nuxt generate` in Nuxt 2.14 would be helpful for my use case in skipping the webpack build.

However, on running the `nuxt generate` command which skips the webpack build and jump straights to the generating of pages, the pages generated seem to be updated (as expected), but the data inside `asyncData` does not seem to be getting updated/refreshed.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
generate: {
    crawler: false,
    async routes() {
      let finalArray = readFinalArrayFromSomeDatabase();

      await fs.writeJson('static/data/index.json', finalArray); // writing new array to static folder

      generateSomeNewRoutes(finalArray); // working correctly!!!
    }
}
```

some **_slug.vue**

```
async asyncData(params) {
    // this runs after previous code runs
    const testArray = require("../../../static/data/index.json"); // this is not updated!!!
}
```

The `index.json` written is updated, but the `index.json` read in asyncData is NOT. Is there some way to trigger the change in asyncData? Or Does that mean I have to always rebuild webpack when my data change and cant use this feature in nuxt 2.14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `asyncData` you are loading the JSON with `require`, which adds the JSON to the webpack build, so it's not updated after that point.

Instead, you can use a [`payload`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-payload) to pass your data through to the asyncData. For example:

```js
  generate: {
    crawler: false,
    async routes() {
      const finalArray = readFinalArrayFromSomeDatabase();

      return generateSomeNewRoutes(finalArray).map(route => ({ route, payload: finalArray }));
    }
}
```

Then in your component:

```js
async asyncData({ payload }) {
  if (payload) {
    // you can now access the entire finalArray via payload
    // though note this will only work at generate time and during dev
    // you should have another solution to fetch/require data differently
  }
}
```

Comment: Understood on the workflow, really appreciate the answer and will give it a try. Wondering what does "you should have another solution to fetch/require data differently" mean? Does that mean I have to consider other cases?

Comment: May i ask if there will be any limitation on the payload size? The finalArray I'm passing is really huge, so wondering if there will be any issue

Comment: Ideally you should have some code that will allow the page to load in development mode (because the payload will only be passed when you run `nuxt generate`). There shouldn't be any limit to the payload size. When you are using full static mode, it's only what `asyncData` *returns* that is inlined into your page.